# How to remove the yellow bar that shows your search term

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

With the latest update of Chrome, some of the developer tools were changed as well, most notably visually was the addition of the big yellow bar (shown below), that pops up when you do a search in the Network Tab.  Does anyone know how to disable this, as it takes up valuable space I'd rather use for viewing Network traffic.

Thanks!
Andrew

[image]

Comment: What version of Chrome are you on? Check at `chrome://version`.

Comment: Sorry, 67.0.3396.99